# What's the difference between event_timestamp and message_time in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-analytics

In Google's Firebase documentation, I found a definition for **message_time** being the message sent timestamp, but I couldn't find one for **event_timestamp**. https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7061705?hl=en

[image: Google BigQuery data from Firebase]

When I converted these times from Epoch to human-readable format, there was a difference of a few seconds (10:14:22 PM vs. 10:14:28 PM). Can someone tell me what the functional difference is between these two fields?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?